# android alarmmanager, BOOT_COMPLETED - not display UI on boot?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

Have an android application that uses the alarmmanager to schedule a task repeating once a day. The application also has a working boot receiver that runs fine when the device is rebooted.  What I need the application to do is to schedule the alarmmanager task on reboot and not launch the GUI associated with the application.   Is this possible?

I have tried:
1.using .putExtra in an attempt to pass a value that could be used to block the UI.  Logging indicates that the intent extra value is not making it to the MainActivity onCreate.

2. Have the boot receiver call my class that schedules the alarm only.  his approach still triggers the application UI to display.
3. attempted to debug the boot process via an adb command to send a boot complete which flat out doesn't work.

Pointers appreciated.

Comment: I set a putExtra value in the boot_completed receiver, check for a bundle on the intent on mainActivity onCreate and only call setContentView, toolbar commands if there is not a bundle on the intent.   Leads to a funky blank screen when the application starts.  Should I maybe use something other than startActivity in my boot_completed receiver?

Comment: You can set the alarm right in the `BroadcastReceiver`, provided you're not doing a bunch of work to get that done, since Receivers aren't meant to live very long. Alternatively, you could start an `IntentService` from the Receiver to set the alarm. There's no need to start an `Activity` to use `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Modified my BOOT_COMPLETED receiver to call content.startService() instead of startActivity.  Call to startService schedules the alarmManager without launching the UI.